# Does there exist a bounded real function with some property?

Tags: functional-inequalities

Does there exist bounded $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(1)>0$ and for every $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$ we have $$f(x+y)^2\geq f(x)^2+2f(xy)+f(y)^2$$

I can't solve it. I've put $y=-x$ and similar stuff but doesn't lead anywhere (at least I don't see the way).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $B<\infty$ is the supremum of $f$. Clearly $B\ge f(1)>0$.  Let $g(\epsilon)= f(1)^2+2(B-\epsilon)+(B-\epsilon)^2$. The hypothesis that $f(1)>0$ implies  $g(0)>B^2$ and by continuity  there exists an $\epsilon>0$ so that $g(\epsilon)>B^2$.    For that $\epsilon$ let $x$ be such that $f(x)>B-\epsilon$.  Then $$f(1+x)^2\ge f(1)^2+2f(x)+f(x)^2$$
$$ \ge f(1)^2+2(B-\epsilon)+(B-\epsilon)^2=g(\epsilon)>B^2,$$
contradicting the assumption that $B$ was the supremum  of $f$.

Comment: I don't get this prove, why $\epsilon$ exist?

Comment: I have tidied up my answer, hopefully making this clear.